# selected element move up and down, but scroll behavior is not working with

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll

I make a list of div tags for listing filename.
and After selecting a div, then I can change focus up and down using Arrow keys

Because I have a long file list, I add `overflow: scroll` to the container
but Scroll does not move along with my focus(so active div disappear from the viewport),
How can I make scroll behavior move down along with active div?

I create an example in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-is-not-moving-with-div-pi640?file=/src/styles.css)

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const keyPress = (e) => {
      if (e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
        setSelectedItem((prev) => Number(prev) - 1);
      }
      if (e.key === "ArrowRight") {
        setSelectedItem((prev) => Number(prev) + 1);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("keydown", keyPress);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", keyPress);
    };
  }, [selectedItem]);

  const onClickDiv = (e) => {
    setSelectedItem(e.target.id);
  };

  const renderList = () => {
    let items = [];
    console.log(selectedItem);
    for (let i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
      items.push(
        <div
          key={i}
          className={`item ${Number(selectedItem) === i ? "active" : ""}`}
          id={i}
          onClick={onClickDiv}
        >
          Item{i}.png
        </div>
      );
    }
    return items;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="list-container">{renderList()}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
.list-container {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.active {
  background-color: orangered;
}
```

### ------------------ EDIT -----------------------

I finally complete this example, I sincerely thank you guys for answering my question.

Here is [code sandbox final code](https://codesandbox.io/s/moving-scorll-in-the-viewport-83j40?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for, Do you want the selected element to move around as you hit the arrow keys ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak Sorry for the unclear question, I want to move the scroll when I met the bottom item of the list or top item of the list in the viewport

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my take on it.

I am using `refs` as well along with `scrollIntoView`.This way we don't have to scroll by a fixed amount and also we only are scrolling when we are at the end of the viewport.

Here's  the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-wqjs6?file=/index.js:0-1765)

I am storing refs of each element.

```
 ref={(ref) => {
            elementRefs.current = { ...elementRefs.current, [i]: ref };
 }}
```

And then we will use `scrollIntoView` when focus changes.

```
const prevItem = elementRefs.current[selectedItem - 1];
prevItem && prevItem.scrollIntoView({ block: "end" });
```

Notice the `{block:"end"}` argument here. It makes sure we only scroll if the element is not in the viewport.

You can learn more about [scrollIntoView here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(0);
  const elementRefs = useRef({});
  useEffect(() => {
    const keyPress = (e) => {
      if (e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
        setSelectedItem((prev) => Number(prev) - 1);
        const prevItem = elementRefs.current[selectedItem - 1];
        prevItem && prevItem.scrollIntoView({ block: "end" });
      }
      if (e.key === "ArrowRight") {
        console.log(elementRefs.current[selectedItem]);
        // if (selectedItem < elementRefs.current.length)
        const nextItem = elementRefs.current[selectedItem + 1];
        nextItem && nextItem.scrollIntoView({ block: "end" });
        setSelectedItem((prev) => Number(prev) + 1);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("keydown", keyPress);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", keyPress);
    };
  }, [selectedItem]);

  const onClickDiv = (e) => {
    setSelectedItem(e.target.id);
  };

  const renderList = () => {
    let items = [];
    console.log(selectedItem);
    for (let i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
      items.push(
        <div
          key={i}
          className={`item ${Number(selectedItem) === i ? "active" : ""}`}
          id={i}
          onClick={onClickDiv}
          ref={(ref) => {
            elementRefs.current = { ...elementRefs.current, [i]: ref };
          }}
        >
          Item{i}.png
        </div>
      );
    }
    return items;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="list-container">{renderList()}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: Is it possible to use useState instead of useRef to the div ref props?

Comment: useState will cause unnecessary re-renders. useRef is the preferred way to store dom element refs.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this problem is to use `ref` in React.

First define a ref using

```
const scrollRef = useRef(null);
```

Then, assign it to your scrolling element like this,

```
<div className="list-container" ref={scrollRef}>
```

What this does is, gives you a reference to the html element inside your code.

`ref.current` is the HTML Div element now.

Now, you can use `scrollBy` method on HTML element to scroll up or down.

Like this,

```
useEffect(() => {
  const keyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
      setSelectedItem((prev) => Number(prev) - 1);
      scrollRef.current.scrollBy(0, -18); // <-- Scrolls the div 18px to the top
    }
    if (e.key === "ArrowRight") {
      setSelectedItem((prev) => Number(prev) + 1);
      scrollRef.current.scrollBy(0, 18);  // <-- Scrolls the div 18px to the bottom
    }
  };
  window.addEventListener("keydown", keyPress);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", keyPress);
  };
}, [selectedItem]);
```

I have given `18` because I know the height of my list item.

I have updated your [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-is-not-moving-with-div-forked-hkbpu?file=/src/App.js:201-689). Check it out.

Comment: Ylour approach is very simple, so I also like this answer, both two answers are great